# Replace value in a table

Tags: sed, io-redirection, table

I have some tables for which I need to replace a field that has a random position in each table.

For information, the table are semicolon separated fields and I would like to replace the field `"datum"` by `"YEAR-MONTH-DAY"`.

So far, I have tried:

```
sed -i 's/datum/YEAR-MONTH-DAY/g' input > output
```

But it just outputs an empty file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As steeldriver astutely pointed out in the comments, you've told sed to `-i` [edit the file in-place](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt). As a result, sed will not provide any output, and so the `>` [redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/117549) will put that *nothing* into the output file.

Either keep the `-i` flag and accept that the `input` file will be updated in-place:

```
sed -i 's/datum/YEAR-MONTH-DAY/g' input
```

or drop the `-i` flag and use the redirection to put the updated contents in the `output` file:

```
sed    's/datum/YEAR-MONTH-DAY/g' input > output
```